# Understanding scoping issues using ClaimsTransformation and DI for access to dbContext

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, claims-based-identity

Currently, I am attempting to implement ClaimsTransformation inside my OnTokenValidated event and I am getting scoping issues. The error I receive is:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IClaimsTransformation' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IConfigureOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectOptions]'.

First, here's the registration of my services.

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
.AddCookie
    (cookie =>
    { 
        cookie.AccessDeniedPath = "/Error";
    });

// This sample uses an in-memory cache for tokens and subscriptions.
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddSession();

// Add application services.
//services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
services.AddSingleton<IGraphAuthProvider, GraphAuthProvider>();
services.AddTransient<IGraphSdkHelper, GraphSdkHelper>();

// DI for claims transformation
services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();

// DEBUG DB (local)
services.AddDbContext<TestContext>(options =>
 options.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TestContext;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"));
```

Next, I register additional services inside my AuthenticationBuilder.

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdOptions> configureOptions)
{
    builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
    builder.AddOpenIdConnect();
    return builder;
}
```

Within my `AzureAdAuthenticationBuilderExtensions` file where I host the OpenIdConnectResponseType events, I pass in the claims principal.

```
},OnTokenValidated = async (context) =>
{
    // Pass in the claims principal to append ACLs
    await _claimsTransformer.TransformAsync(context.Principal);
}
```

And here is the snippet where I attempt to access my dbContext through DI which causes the scoping issues.

```
private readonly Test.Models.TestContext _dbContext;

public ClaimsTransformer(TestContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
}
```

I understand the overall issue of a service depending on another service with a shorter lifespan, however, I have followed several different resources online to cobble this implementation together and I'm not quite sure how to resolve the issue and allow access to my dbContext service within my `ClaimsTransformation` implementation. I did see entirely different solutions that didn't use claimstransformation at all and instead elected to use a `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` though I don't know if that's just an alternative or is, in fact, the current encouraged way to implement this functionality.

https://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2017/08/customizing-claims-for-authorization-in.html

Also, any critiques to code and/or concerns are always welcome, I always appreciate an opportunity to learn! As an addendum, I am working with AzureAD but do not have the capability to create groups within this Azure instance and so I am planning on creating user entries in my DB and storing their associated roles for use in authorization in my application. Hence the need to append a new claim to the principal once a user authenticates and the need to perform a lookup in my DB to see what roles the user should have.